# Keyboard is working but not typing in any app including terminal

Tags: keyboard, 20.04, live-usb

I tested the OS before installing on my laptop (Lenovo IdealPad L340 Gaming) on a USB stick. Everything seems to work fine and I managed to connect to my home WiFi network and typed the password.

However, after opening Firefox I noticed that it doesn't write or even press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, even in other apps and notepads and terminal have the same issue, the shortcuts however, like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, are working fine - even the function keys like volume up/down.

I tried to open the on screen keyboard, but it didn't show up. And I tried to.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution, but i don't understand how it worked yet...

I have re flashed Ubuntu to the USB stick as GPT this time not as MBR. Now I'm typing this on Ubuntu :) i hope this helps anyone in the future

Comment: This has absolutely no correlation with what was described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I could type in the "search" text field in the application overview, but not in any apps including Firefox and Settings.

What solved it for me was going to Settings -> Accessibility and turning on Screen Keyboard. From that moment my physical keyboard also started working normally.

I don't have the slightest idea what was going on, just leaving this here cause it might help someone else who ends up at this question.